# Is Junkrat's Rip-tire destructible and/or is it destroyed upon his death?

Tags: overwatch

While playing last night a Junkrat player used his ultimate on me. His Rip-tire was inline with him and I was shooting in that direction.

I know that shortly after Junkrat was dead and his Rip-tire never reached me.

Can you destroy Junkrat's Rip-tire by shooting it?

Does the Rip-tire get destroyed if Junkrat is killed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Rip Tire actually has an HP bar which means it can tank a certain amount of damage before it blows up.  It has 100 effective HP. This means that you can shoot at it to blow it up, explosives also seem to work better against it to blow it up early.  High speed, large splash area and early trigger possibility means, in general, you should try to get far away from the sound so you have more time to blow up the tire.

The information presented in the other answer is factually incorrect. If Junkrat dies while Rip Tire is still in play, it will not be automatically be destroyed, and can still be controlled until either its duration runs out or it is destroyed.

[Source:](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/junkrat.html#tire)

> - When used, you will be able to control the Rip-Tire while your Junkrat
>     character stays still and is vulnerable while you control the tire. 
>     If Junkrat dies, you will still be able to control the tire until it
>     explodes.

Upon detonating the Rip Tire or having an enemy destroy it, if you have died, the screen will show your dead body, then show the killcam for it.

Comment: You're right, I just tested it in the training stage. Edit your answer to contain all of the info I asked for and I'll accept it.

Comment: IIRC the riptire has only 100 HP (that's the number shown at least). Where does the 600 come from?

Comment: Meant that it does 600 damage, sorry bout that

Answer (score -1):

> Can you destroy Junkrat's Rip-tire by shooting it?

Yes you can, you normally can see the health bar above it.

Even one hanzo arrow is enough :D

> Does the Rip-tire get destroyed if Junkrat is killed?

Yes it disappears and does not do any Damage.

Comment: Thank you for the info on the health bar! Very useful, it's hard to notice these things with all the mayhem that's going on :P. Do you have any source or example for the Rip-tire not being destroyed when Junkrat dies?

Comment: @JoãoNeves just asked a bigger community, the rip tire just disappears without doing any damage, gonna correct that

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the rip-tire deals any damage if it gets destroyed by shooting it?

Comment: @JoãoNeves actually this is another question but

no rip-tire doesnt do any damage when it disappears/gets destroyed

Comment: I've personally controlled the rip tire after death and got play of the game.

Comment: @GarrettJ The answer was written by someone who tried googling for it as opposed to actually playing the game and understanding the mechanics